# PHP Explode exclude

Tags: php, function, character, explode

I have a string with data like this:

> 8487613 1298296324 1a6ad892e547da07f35221fdfe6f70dd "|MoDo|" 178.211.28.126 "Battlefield Bad Company 2" "BC Stuff and name" "Violation (AIMBOT) #50246"

In my PHP I use explode like this:

```
$more_info = explode(' ', $banned_players);
```

But it separates spaces in "Battlefield Bad Company 2" and I don't want that to happen.

So is there any way for explode with spaces but not between "" characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php). It's intended for tab- or comma-separated values, but it works very well with just the space as separator:

```
print_r(str_getcsv('8487613 1298296324 1a6ad892e547da07f35221fdfe6f70dd "|MoDo|" 178.211.28.126 "Battlefield Bad Company 2"', " "));
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8487613
    [1] => 1298296324
    [2] => 1a6ad892e547da07f35221fdfe6f70dd
    [3] => |MoDo|
    [4] => 178.211.28.126
    [5] => Battlefield Bad Company 2
    [6] => BC Stuff and name
    [7] => Violation (AIMBOT) #50246
)
```

Comment: Or `fgetcsv`, `fseek` and `php://temp` if < 5.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) instead

Comment: Well I'm not really good with regex and I want to finish this code quickly. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Explode the " character, you'll have 3 arrays, then explode first array and last array with space character, and use `array_push()` and `array_merge()` to merge them all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) with one whitespace as delimiter.

Note: This only works, if you have only one character delimiters.